# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: null KNN algorithm is not supported

Tags: solr, knn, solrj

After i create the documents with the Vector's following the documentation below, i have the following error from Solr logs:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: null KNN algorithm is not supported
h
```

Screenshot issue

[image: 1]

This is the part of Java code I'm testing:

```
final SolrClient client = getSolrClient();

final SolrInputDocument d1 = new SolrInputDocument();
d1.setField("id", "1");
d1.setField("vector", Arrays.asList(1.0f, 2.5f, 3.7f, 4.1f));


final SolrInputDocument d2 = new SolrInputDocument();
d2.setField("id", "2");
d2.setField("vector", Arrays.asList(1.5f, 5.5f, 6.7f, 65.1f));

client.add(Arrays.asList(d1, d2));
```

This is the documentation for my try: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/dense-vector-search.html

Comment: which solr version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-16588 .
A solution is coming soon!